# Canvas Game Development and performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

There seems to be some differing opinions about this going from blog to blog, video to video, and forum to forum. This is specifically for the 2D context for the canvas tag, not WebGL. I know that WebGL would give me better performance but my goal is to understand how the canvas tag works in its 2D context.

I hear that pre-rendering your objects in a "virtual" offscreen canvas is probably the best for performance which makes sense seeing the browser wouldn't literally be drawing it.  People then say to grab the data from that canvas using "getImageData" which from my understanding returns a base64 code that you can apply to a canvas that is added to the DOM using "putImageData".  Wouldn't this be a huge performance hit?

Should I render the entire seen for the game on this virtual canvas and then put it to the visible one using this method inside of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  I recommend using requestAnimationFrame() and inside the draw() part of your game loop, draw all separate objects to an offscreen canavs, and then do one get/put image to the visible canvas.  While this may seem to be a performance hit, but when you have many objects being drawn, this overhead of get/put image is actually negligible.

Comment: So what you are saying is if I make something like and RPG, and have a bunch of different tiles, i should render them all in the offscreen canvas, then get the data from that canvas and put them over to the visible one?

Comment: Yes :) There is a small overhead to each tile being put on the canvas, so when you draw on the offscreen buffer, its quicker because it doesn't have to draw to memory and screen, it just does it to memory.

Comment: Would multiple canvases be more beneficial to game development? One for the tiles, and one for my main character for example?

Comment: No, there is no benefit to having multiple offscreen canvases, unless you're using them to store images to be reused

Comment: I mean for the main stage.

Answer (score 2):

The Canvas is just an image, and from my experience there is no difference between using a canvas or an image in terms of performance.

Offscreen or on the canvas is no different, they will both take advantage of the GPU wherever possible.

Using `context.getImageData()`, `context.createImageData()`, and `context.putImageData()` should be avoided for realtime rendering, It does not take advantage of the GPU and any processing you do to it will be done in main memory by Javascript. Though the data is stored in a typed array `Uint8ClampedArray` and can be converted to any type of typed array, such as a `Uint32Array` allowing you to handle a single pixel with one variable, rather than 4. There are also many native functions for typed arrays that provide much quicker array manipulation than the standard Javascript array.

The limiting factor for images (including canvas as image) is the amount of GPU RAM available, when you exceed the amount of RAM available the browser will start swapping images into GPU RAM as they are needed, when it does so this blocks the GPU's ability to render, and the transfer from Main RAM to the GPU RAM is slow in comparison to normal RAM access. When this happens you will instantly see a loss in frame rate. As there are a huge variety of platforms that the browsers can run on and no way to know the machines capabilities you should be careful when you publish realtime applications.

If you have written a game with high resolution images for a high end desktop machine, it will not perform very well on tablets and low end laptops. To mitigate this problem downsample the images to match the screen resolution. Using a hires background image on a device that is 1/8th the resolution is putting undue strain on the hardware. Devices are made to handle the resolution of their screens, going over this resolution  will have a major unnecessary performance hit. This is where you can use an offscreen canvas to render the image at the native resolution of the device and then dump the original hires image. There will be no loss of quality, but a huge gain in performance, turning something that is unplayable into playable. This applies to all graphic resources. Never store and use images at a resolution higher then the device you are using can display.

Because there is such a variety of things you can do with the canvas the best way to find out what runs best is to experiment. Monitor the frame rate and try different approaches to the problem at hand. If the frame rate improves you have found a better way of doing thing, if the frame rate drops then you have used the wrong method.

Comment: This pretty much went against what most people are saying on the web.  The only way I see it being beneficial is using a tilemap that doesn't move. Once the character reaches the edge of the screen , it goes to the next.  Also, where are your references for the claims that you make in the post?

Comment: @CalebPrenger I don't need referance, anyone with a browser and a little time can test performance of the canvas. Just load images, create canvases, and render them.  See how many you can render befor the frame rate drops, that is how you will find what works and what does not. The reality is that most canvas performance issues are unrelated to the canvas, it is bad Javascript coding practices that do not become apparent till performance matters, then the canvas is blamed.

Comment: I don't think you understand the point of multiple canvases.  One would be background, which for the most part I will not have to redraw.  The one above it would be for my sprite which I would need to redraw. I would not redraw the entire canvas though I would redraw only the section my character was previously in.  Of course using getImageData and putImageData on a canvas in the loop would bog your game down. It's not meant for that from what I can understand.

Comment: @CalebPrenger having the canvas as a separate DOM layer, or drawing it each frame with `ctx.drawImage` will make very little difference both are rendered by the GPU.Also getImageData is not meant for real time rendering at all, nor is it a offscreen canvas. This creates a copy of an image as offscreen canvas `function copyImg(img){ var c = document.createElement("canvas"); c.width = img.width; c.height = img.height;(c.ctx = c.getContext("2d")).drawImage(img,0,0);
return c;}` Its high performance, uses GPU to draw to, and renders as quickly as any image or Dom element.